# How to eliminate "click effect " on <img> element in chrome(android system) by CSS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

How to eliminate "click effect " on < img > element in chrome(android system) by CSS.

When I put an  element on a webpage. Every time when I click it in my android chrome, a light green rectangle covers that img. I don't want this 'click effect', how to eliminate it?

Comment: probably there are ::focus or ::active pseudoclass that apply their default styles on image or on their parent element. Use img::focus, img::active{.....} (or applied to respective parent) to Override them with your styles when the item is clicked

Comment: It seems not the background property. but a rectangle corve the img .@Sim1-81

Comment: post a reproducible example of your html and css

Comment: I found the answer. I am using the w3.css frame. And using w3-button for that image. when I remove this class, every things eliminate. I currently have no idea how does the w3-button cause that effect. [w3-button](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_buttons.asp) @Sim1-81

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer my self. That is because of the cursor property set to "pointer". {cursor: pointer}.

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar filtro. Por exemplo:
img{filter:   ;
}

Comment: Thanks. But I figure out In my code, that is because I set the cursor property to "pointer"